# "It helped the north remember" or "It helped the north remembered" or "It helped the north remembers"

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

https://www.lingq.com/el/lesson/lesson-28-the-gettysburg-address-431424/

***It helped the north remember*** what they were fighting for-- freedom and equality for all people, black and white and strengthened Lincoln’s personal position as their leader remembered to this day as one of the greatest American Presidents of all time.

Why in the beginning of the above context there is "remember" not "remembers" or "remembered"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb "remember" is in the "bare infinitive" form, which is "remember".  The structure is

> (subject) [help] (someone) (bare infinitive)

So we could have

> I helped her play tennis.
>
> It will help them be good
>
> She helps her mum wash the clothes

In each case the finite verb is "help" and the other verb (play/be/wash) is a bare infinitive.

Comment: Thanks, does that form of structure is only for the verb "help" or it is for all of the verbs?     notice that English is not my mother tongue.

Comment: most verb, but not all, would use a "to infinitive" or an -ing gerund.  Some common verbs have a bare infinitive: "make him play" or "hear him play". In some cases it is optional, or different forms are allowed, but have different meaning. There are already lot and lots of questions about infinitives and gerunds here.